# Problems with sendRedirect() function

Tags: java, jsp, session, tomcat

I have this strange problem with sendRedirect function which i can't explain.
I have a **header page** as Header.jsp as :

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" language="java" import="java.sql.*,java.util.*" errorPage="" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Online Exam Portal</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body{
        background-color : lightgreen;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<%
if(session.getAttribute("userid")==null)
{
   response.sendRedirect("signup.html");
}
%>
<img src="exam_header01.jpg"/>
<br />
Welcome <%=session.getAttribute("userid")+"This is Working"%>
<a href="ChangePassword.jsp">Change Password</a> 
<a href="logout.jsp">Logout</a> 

<hr/>
```

i have **included** this header page in all the pages, i did this since i wanted to prevent the users who don't have valid session and redirect to signup page but it **doesn't redirects**
instead it shows Welcome null and also :
1> If i write anything inside that if statement it works fine! , like :

```
if(session.getAttribute("userid")==null)
{
   response.sendRedirect("signup.html");//this is not executed
   out.println("This Runs");//this String is printed
}
```

2> If i write the same code inside the main page(i.e after header page) it works fine!
3> And most importantly the code works when i replace it by :

```
<jsp:forward page="signup.html"/>
```

What could be the problem here. it would be really appreciated if anyone can explain with examples.

---

Update :-
Even If i print to my page after Redirect it will work if i use if statement use after including the Header :

```
<jsp:include page="Header.jsp"/>
        <%if(session.getAttribute("userid")==null)
{ 
response.sendRedirect("signup.html");
out.println("I cant See this because page is redirected ");
} 
%>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not way to handle un-authenticated access. Use authentication filter instead.

Comment: @Masud thank you for your comment. I have learned about this technology recently so i dont have much idea. I am just trying :)

Comment: Try to give absolute path to send redirect method.

Comment: @nishu still doesn't works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, this isn't the best way to achieve what you want to achieve.

That said, the problem you are seeing is as a result of using the wrong type of include. You are using request time include (`<jsp:include page="..." />`) which processes the included page and inserts the output (if any) into the current page. If you call `response.sendRedirect()` from an included page it is ignored. Hence your current solution doesn't work.

You would need to use a translation time include (`<%@ include file=... %>`) which takes the source of the included page, inserts it into the source of the current page and then processed the current page as if it was a single JSP.

Answer (score 0):

From the javadoc:

> After using this method, the response should be considered to be committed and should not be written to.

You don't respect this, since you continue to print to the response after sendRedirect().

The main problem is in your architecture. JSPs are view components. They should not contain scriptlets, and should not redirect. They should only generate HTML markup from beans stored in request attributes by a controller, written in Java, as a servlet or action of your preferred MVC framework. And to generate this markup, they should only use the JSP EL, the JSTL and other custom tags.

Instead of repeating the login check in every JSP, which is extremely error-prone and repetitive, you should have a servlet filter which intercepts all the requests, makes the check, and let the next component (a controller) do its job of the user is authenticated.

```
request --> authentication filter --- if authenticated ---> controller --- forward to ---> JSP
                  |
                  |--- if not authenticated --- redirect to --> authentication controller --- forward to ---> login.jsp
```

Comment: I still can't understand then why did it worked inside the main page(i.e after including the header) and the example in which i printed after response was for checking and even if i removed that statement its not working :(

Comment: All the rest of the page (Welcome... until the end of the page) is also printed, since it's not part of an `else` block. Why it doesn't work when part of an included page is probably caused by a glitch in Tomcat, but you shouldn't do that anyway. Also note that the text before the login check has also already been printed, although it shouldn't. Use MVC.

Answer (score 0):

For authentication purposes, use Filters.

A Filter is nothing but a Java class that is used to preprocess the request before it is forwarded to the resource the user asked for. 
**Eg.** if you have mapped your filter class with a servlet, then as and when the request comes in for this servlet, it is initially intercepted by the filter class(which contains your authentication code) and if it succeeds in authentication then only the request is forwarded to the servlet. This makes the authentication more easy and flexible.
 
For this, you need to map your filter class with the servlet inside web.xml.
*In short, response.sendRedirect() would not serve your purpose and you have to ultimately rely on filters.*